# SQL Query: Rollup The Output of This SQL Query SO Each Assessment Has 1 Row Instead of Multiples

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am running a SQL query on a SQL 2000 server to grab a bunch of data from the database joining multiple tables. Everything is centered around an Assessment ID. Each Assessment has rows in a table called LabResultDetails but the current output exports 6-8 rows for each assessment(one for each result in LabResultDetails Table).

Is there a way I can modify this query to export the data in one row per assessment and each LabResultDetail Name is a corresponding column and the Value is the value for that row (Each Row will have one column for each possible LabResultDetail name)?

Here is the query and ouput:

```
SELECT [a].ID,
   [p].FirstName,
   [p].LastName,
   [lrd].Name,
   [lrd].Value,
   [hp].*
FROM   Assessments [a]
   INNER JOIN LabResultDetails [lrd]
     ON [a].LabResultID = [lrd].LabResultID
   INNER JOIN EHealthProfiles [hp]
     ON [a].ProfileID = [hp].ID
   INNER JOIN Patients [p]
     ON [a].PatientID = [p].ID
```

Output:[image]

The issue is, I need each possible value or [lrd].Name to be a column in the output and the value of that column to be [lrd].Value instead of having a row for each [lrd] record that is associated to the [a] record.

Comment: Time to learn modern, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax.  Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause!

Comment: On top of @GordonLinoff suggestion of proper syntax and query structure, you are looking for a `PIVOT` solution here.  Many examples exist of this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have updated the query to use inner joins now, but still can't get a pivot call to work. Also added info noting this is on a SQL 2000 server.

Comment: @IsaacByrne . . . SQL Server 2000 is archaic.  You should upgrade your server to software that has been supported in the last decade or so.

Comment: I agree it is SUPER archaic haha I just needed to pull some data for a client from a super old DB they used ages ago. Thankfully I figured it out and hopefully will never need to mess with it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to working using GROUP BY along with MIN() for the values I was trying to convert to columns. Below is the updated query that is giving me the desired result:

```
SELECT [a].ID,
   [a].CreateDate,
   [p].FirstName,
   [p].LastName,
   [p].Gender,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Epinephrine' Then Value End ) As Epinephrine,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Norepinephrine' Then Value End ) As Norepinephrine,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Melatonin' Then Value End ) As Melatonin,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'DHEAS2' Then Value End ) As DHEAS2,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'NorepiEpi' Then Value End ) As NorepiEpi,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Cortisols5' Then Value End ) As Cortisols5,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'DHES1' Then Value End ) As DHES1,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Glutamate' Then Value End ) As Glutamate,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'DHEAS3' Then Value End ) As DHEAS3,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Cortisols4' Then Value End ) As Cortisols4,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Histamine' Then Value End ) As Histamine,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'seronton' Then Value End ) As seronton,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Epinephrine' Then Value End ) As Epinephrine,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'DHES2' Then Value End ) As DHES2,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Potassium' Then Value End ) As Potassium,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Sodium' Then Value End ) As Sodium,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'PEA' Then Value End ) As PEA,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'DHES3' Then Value End ) As DHES3,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'DHEAS1' Then Value End ) As DHEAS1,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Cortisols6' Then Value End ) As Cortisols6,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Dopamine' Then Value End ) As Dopamine,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Gaba' Then Value End ) As Gaba,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Estradiol' Then Value End ) As Estradiol,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Progesterone' Then Value End ) As Progesterone,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Cortisols2' Then Value End ) As Cortisols2,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'blank' Then Value End ) As blank,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'NULL' Then Value End ) As NULLED,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Serotonin' Then Value End ) As Serotonin,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Cortisols3' Then Value End ) As Cortisols3,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Creatinine' Then Value End ) As Creatinine,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'cat' Then Value End ) As cat,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Cortisols1' Then Value End ) As Cortisols1,
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = '3Methoxytyramine' Then Value End ) As '3Methoxytyramine',
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Norepi/Epi' Then Value End ) As '3NorepiEpi',
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = '5HIAA' Then Value End ) As '5HIAA',
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Chloride' Then Value End ) As '5Chloride',
   Min ( Case When [lrd].Name = 'Testosterone' Then Value End ) As Testosterone,
   [hp].PatientID,
   [hp].DOB,
   [hp].HeightFeet,
   [hp].HeightInches,
   [hp].Weight,
   [hp].RecentWeight,
   [hp].Pregnant,
   [hp].MoodIssues,
   [hp].AnxietyOrNervousness,
   [hp].OnEdge,
   [hp].TroubleFallingAsleep,
   [hp].BiPolar,
   [hp].MoreForgetful,
   [hp].Headaches,
   [hp].LosingWeight,
   [hp].ChocolateCravings,
   [hp].CarbCravings,
   [hp].EatingDisorder,
   [hp].AutismPDD,
   [hp].OnMedication,
   CAST([hp].Medications AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   [hp].FallingAsleep,
   [hp].StayingAsleep,
   CAST([hp].HoursSleepPerNight AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   [hp].DifficultyFocusing,
   [hp].ShortMemoryLoss,
   [hp].LongMemoryLoss,
   [hp].ProteinServings,
   [hp].VaryProtein,
   [hp].WaterDaily,
   [hp].EnergyLevels,
   [hp].Suicide,
   [hp].CryEasily,
   [hp].FutureBleak,
   [hp].GasOrBloating,
   [hp].TroubleDigesting,
   CAST([hp].Supplement1 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement1Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement2 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement2Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement3 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement3Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement4 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement4Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement5 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement5Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement6 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement6Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   [hp].FromMyAccount,
   [hp].Disclaimer,
   [hp].DateEntered
FROM   Assessments [a]
   INNER JOIN LabResultDetails [lrd]
     ON [a].LabResultID = [lrd].LabResultID
   INNER JOIN EHealthProfiles [hp]
     ON [a].ProfileID = [hp].ID
   INNER JOIN Patients [p]
     ON [a].PatientID = [p].ID
GROUP BY [a].ID,
     [a].CreateDate,
     [p].FirstName,
     [p].LastName,
     [p].Gender,
     [hp].PatientID,
   [hp].DOB,
   [hp].HeightFeet,
   [hp].HeightInches,
   [hp].Weight,
   [hp].RecentWeight,
   [hp].Pregnant,
   [hp].MoodIssues,
   [hp].AnxietyOrNervousness,
   [hp].OnEdge,
   [hp].TroubleFallingAsleep,
   [hp].BiPolar,
   [hp].MoreForgetful,
   [hp].Headaches,
   [hp].LosingWeight,
   [hp].ChocolateCravings,
   [hp].CarbCravings,
   [hp].EatingDisorder,
   [hp].AutismPDD,
   [hp].OnMedication,
   CAST([hp].Medications AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   [hp].FallingAsleep,
   [hp].StayingAsleep,
   CAST([hp].HoursSleepPerNight AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   [hp].DifficultyFocusing,
   [hp].ShortMemoryLoss,
   [hp].LongMemoryLoss,
   [hp].ProteinServings,
   [hp].VaryProtein,
   [hp].WaterDaily,
   [hp].EnergyLevels,
   [hp].Suicide,
   [hp].CryEasily,
   [hp].FutureBleak,
   [hp].GasOrBloating,
   [hp].TroubleDigesting,
   CAST([hp].Supplement1 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement1Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement2 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement2Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement3 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement3Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement4 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement4Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement5 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement5Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement6 AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   CAST([hp].Supplement6Capsules AS VARCHAR(5000)),
   [hp].FromMyAccount,
   [hp].Disclaimer,
   [hp].DateEntered

ORDER BY [a].CreateDate DESC
```